# Is it possible to have dual internet connection: Local plus internet?

Tags: networking, connection, local

So we have a local network at work that connects to the internet and can be accessed remotely from home. Every now and then the internet connection drops even though the local network is still functional. This prevents users from accessing the network remotely.

We need to have a backup computer which can be remotely accessed through a different internet connection (maybe a mobile stick or something). I am wondering if it is possible to have such a system setup where the computer is connected to the local network and at the same time use a different adapter to connect to the internet. The end result would be to have the remote user access network resources.

Any help would be much appreciated? I am thinking that the computer will treat the two connections as separate but I hope that I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows server then you can do that using routing and [remote access protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469653.aspx).

You can also use Microsoft [Forefront Threat Management Gateway](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff355324.aspx).

If you are an open source fan, then go for a [PFSence](https://www.pfsense.org/download/) comunity edition which is available on Linux platform.

There are many other options as well. if you can let me know which platform are you planning on then I can give you more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The windows option would be the best for us and I think the remote access protocol seems like the least amount of work.